# Java PrintWriter to file (on a mac) not working

Tags: java, macos, file-io, printwriter

I've read several threads on here and still can't find out why `PrintWriter` isn't printing to file and is instead throwing a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. I've checked the file location, I've checked the upper/lowercases in the file path. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong:

```
    File output = new File("/Users/<myname>/Documents/javaoutput.txt");
    output.getParentFile().mkdir();

    PrintWriter writer = new Printwriter(output);
```

Comment: What does the exception message say? Show us the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking whether the target directory `/Users/<myname>/Documents` exists or whether the attempt to create it succeeded. `new PrintWriter()` would throw a `FileNotFoundException` if the target directory didn't exist.

Something like this might work better:

```
File output = new File("/Users/<myname>/Documents/javaoutput.txt");
File dir = output.getParentFile();
if (!dir.isDirectory() && !dir.mkdirs()) {
    // handle could not create directory
    throw new SomeException("Could not create target directory '" + dir + "'");
}
PrintWriter writer = new Printwriter(output);
```

I'm using `mkdirs()` here instead of `mkdir()` to create the entire directory path (`/Users`, `/Users/<myname>`, and `/Users/<myname>/Documents`) if necessary. You should decide what your program should do when it couldn't create the directory and add the correct code for that case.